# Contentful + Azure static web apps trigger deployment

Tags: azure, next.js, contentful, azure-static-web-app

I have a next.js application on Azure static web apps. I've got it building on commit to github (via github actions). Next task is for changes on contentful to trigger a build on Azure.

Am pretty new to Azure, can anyone advise how I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contentful provides the ability to use webhooks, these are URLs to hit when content is changed. Using these you can use a webhook trigger in the github action to trigger the build and inturn the deploy.

https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/concepts/webhooks/
https://kontent.ai/blog/how-to-trigger-github-action-using-webhook-with-no-code/

Comment: My question was on changes in Contentful triggering a deployment in Azure. Are you suggesting this have something to do with Github?

Comment: I completly misunderstood, I will update my answer.

Comment: Great so I can call a Webhook to trigger a Github action which in turn will build on Azure. That makes sense.

However would it be bad practice rather than connecting Contentful directly to Azure?

Comment: I would not say so, this has the advantage that the secrets needed to connect to Azure are not shared with Contentful and are kept in one place in Github.

Comment: This worked a treat thanks so will upvote. 
For anyone else who comes across this, this article helped me a lot.
https://whitep4nth3r.com/blog/how-to-github-actions-contentful-webhooks-to-show-latest-blog-posts-readme/

Comment: I also completely forgot that Next.js static incremental regeneration will enable the users to do the fetching for me, which potentially would not require the need for the Contentful webhook

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration